# JSON API property names and Swagger documentation for proper response modeling

Tags: json, rest, swagger, json-api

I'm seeking the best way for documenting my rest API response according to JSON API and also how to describe it in Swagger YAML documentation.

My API receives a word and a list of URLs and returns how many times the given word appears in each website provided. My first take for the successful response was:

```
{
    "data": {
        "foo": {
            "http://www.foobar.com": 12,
            "http://www.bar.com": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Using the word and the URLs as [property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065841/json-best-practice-for-property-names).

I'd like to know if it is a good practice according to JSON API and if yes, how to document it in Swagger YAML:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: How many times a given word appears in each site provided? This API answer it
  version: 1.0.0
  title: WordApp
  contact:
    email: foo@bar.com

  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html

paths:
  /:
    get:
      summary: returns how many times a given word appears in each provided URL
      description: |
        By passing in the appropriate options, you can search for
        the number of occurrences of a given word in each URL provided
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - in: query
        name: word
        description: pass a word for looking up its occurrences in each site
        required: true
        type: string
      - in: query
        name: url
        description: a list of valid URLs
        type: string
        required: true
      responses:
        200:
          description: search results matching criteria
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/Data'
        500:
          description: Internal Server Error
definitions:
  Data:
    type: object
    required:
    - word
    - url
    - value
    properties:
      word:
        type: string
        example: Brazil
      url:
        type: string
        example: 'https://www.nytimes.com/'
      value:
        type: integer
        example: 12
```

If it is not the best practice, what would be a better way of modeling my response?

Comment: Is `foo` the "word" in your example?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it is

Comment: Are you trying to implement [JSON API specification](https://jsonapi.org/)? Your example does not look so but your question is tagged with the spec.